# text dissapears when cursor is not on input field css

Tags: html, css

here is my css code:

```
#text3 {
    background: #333;
    color: #ccc;
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: 1s all ease;
    outline: 0;
}

#text3:hover {
    width: 250px;
}
```

and here is my html code:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="text3"/>
```

So my problem is that when a user's cursor is on input field it becomes larger and thats fine but when he types something in it and it's cursor goes away the text field becomes smaller and there is no text in there. I know that field should become small when user's cursor is not on text field but why does the text dissapear? i hope you can help me. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should style for `focus` state too.

```
#text3:focus,
#text3:hover {
    width: 250px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shiralizadeh/fx3epda5/)

**Update:**

do this using jQuery and never back to first state

```
$('input').on('focus', function () {
    $(this).addClass('Big');
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shiralizadeh/fx3epda5/1/)

Comment: it worked when user's cursor goes away but when i click on the other input fields text dissapears again.